# Save ringtone and get it again

Tags: android, android-sharedpreferences

I'm working on an app in which I get the current ringtone and save it in sharedprefrences and get it again. I'm trying like this, but its not working. Please tell me where the mistake is? I am new to android. Please tell me with code.

```
Uri currentRintoneUri = RingtoneManager.getActualDefaultRingtoneUri(context
                                    .getApplicationContext(), RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE);
Ringtone currentRingtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(context, currentRintoneUri);
String stringUri;
stringUri = currentRingtone.toString();

sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPRE, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String current = sharedpreferences.getString(CUR, "");
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
editor.putString(CUR, stringUri);
editor.commit();
t1.setText("Current Ringtone : " + currentRingtone.getTitle(context));

Ringtone currentRing = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(context, Uri.parse(current));
//  uri = Uri.parse(current);
currentRing.play();
```